# Windows 8 - how to disable close application gesture?

Tags: c#, windows, microsoft-metro, gesture

I'm writing app in Metro UI that will be used in stand with touch screen. This application must be protected against the possibility of its closure. How disable close gesture (drag finger down)?

Comment: You want http://winsupersite.com/windows-8/blue-s-clues-kiosk-mode

Comment: dup of http://superuser.com/questions/634363/is-it-possible-to-disable-winrt-app-close-gesture-pull-app-from-top-to-bottom